# Nextjs env file data not being read in production

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

We have a site using API routes to fetch data. Locally the site is running `localhost:3000` and the API routes work fine for both `GET` and `POST` requests. On our production environment, Next is running on `localhost:8080`. The site runs and works as expected except for the API routes, none of theme are returning data...

We have a `.env.local` in development passing values to the files in `/api` and on the server we have a `.env`, but from testing it seems as though the env values aren't being read.

Do you have to do anything to allow this data to be used in production? i don't want to expose the values to the browser using `NEXT_PUBLIC`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What hosting service are you using in production?